# How to prevent users to access embedded video files in an intranet?

Tags: html, video, embed, file-permissions

I need to publish an HTML page in an intranet containing the index of some video files, also located on the network. From the main page I thought of pointing, for each video, to a separate html page in which to incorporate it.

I would like to know if it is possible to prevent users from accessing video files directly by browsing the network resources. In practice, the videos should be visible only through the html pages but the relative .mp4 files should not be accessible in any other way (for example by making copy and paste via file explorer). Is it technically possible?

Finally, to prevent download from html pages I thought deactivating the right button on the embedded videos also if it's not the solution for all browsers.

Comment: You can't really prevent it. Disabling right click will not prevent using utilities like curl. Signed URLs are about the best you an do without DRM.

Comment: I wonder if you could make use of video streaming, [see here](https://medium.com/better-programming/video-stream-with-node-js-and-html5-320b3191a6b6). Your server would need to have a script to load chunks and then your JS client loads the pieces and sends them to the video element. However I am not sure if you can disable "Save as" on HTML video elements - it would be worth some research. Note though that this only makes it harder to download, and a committed user will find a way around little roadblocks like this.